# Rails - How to use custom attribute in where?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Order model in which I have datetime column *start* and int columns *arriving_dur*, *drop_off_dur*, etc.. which are durations in seconds from *start*

Then in my model I have

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  def finish_time
    self.start + self.arriving_duration + self.drop_off_duration
  end
  # other  def something_time ... end
end
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
Order.where(finish_time: Time.now..(Time.now+2.hours) )
```

But of course I can't, because there's no such column finish_time. How can I achieve such result?

I've read 4 possible solutions on SA:

- eager load all orders and select it with filter - that would not work well if there were more orders
- have parametrized scope for each time I need but that means soo much code duplication
- have sql function for each time and bind it to model with select() - it's just pain
- somehow use http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute ? But I have no idea how to use it for my case or whether it even solves the problem I have.

Do you have any idea or some 'best practice' how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: I would just prefer the field to persist in database (even if it's computed from other attributes) to save myself all the headache of creating complex queries and debugging issues later. Add hook in model which update the column if one of those field change and that should do the trick

Comment: that's correct, and have in mind that you are talking about Order model, that maybe will be accessed a lot of time, so having a complex query that will be accessed all the time, doesn't seems optimum. @kiddorails comments seems to be the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I will go that way, thank you @kiddorails!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different options to implement this behaviour.

1. Add an additional `finish_time` column and update it whenever you update/create your time values. This could be done in rails (with either `before_validation` or `after_save` callbacks) or as psql triggers.

   ```
   class Order < ApplicationRecord
     before_validation :update_finish_time

     private
     def update_finish_time
       self.finish_time = start_time + arriving_duration.seconds + drop_off_duration.seconds
     end
   end
   ```

   This is especially useful when you need `finish_time` in many places throughout your app. It has the downside that you need to manage that column with extra code and it stores data you actually already have. The upside is that you can easily create an index on that column should you ever have many orders and need to search on it.

   An option could be to implement the finish-time update as a postgresql trigger instead of in rails. This has the benefit of being independent from your rails application (e.g. when other sources/scripts access your db too) but has the downside of splitting your business logic into many places (ruby code, postgres code).
2. Your second option is adding a virtual column just for your query.

   ```
   def orders_within_the_next_2_hours
     finishing_orders = Order.select("*, (start_time + (arriving_duration + drop_off_duration) * interval '1 second') AS finish_time")
     Order.from("(#{finishing_orders.to_sql}) AS orders").where(finish_time: Time.now..(Time.now+2.hours) )
   end
   ```

   The code above creates the SQL query for `finishing_order` which is the `order` table with the additional `finish_time` column. In the second line we use that `finishing_orders` SQL as the FROM clause ("cleverly" aliased to `orders` so rails is happy). This way we can query `finish_time` as if it was a normal column.

   The SQL is written for relatively old postgresql versions (I guess it works for 9.3+). If you use `make_interval` instead of multiplying with `interval '1 second'` the SQL might be a little more readable (but needs newer postgresql version, 9.4+ I think).